# Key navigation, event on press Enter on keyboard

Tags: extjs, keyboard

Hello i am want make event on press key <kbd>Enter</kbd> on keyboard. I am do this:

```
 listeners: {
    afterRender: function (thisForm, options) {
        this.keyMap = Ext.create(
            'Ext.util.KeyMap',
            this.el,
            [
                {
                    key: 13,
                    fn: this.submitOnEnter,
                    scope: this
                }
            ]
        );
    }
},

submitOnEnter: function (e) {
    if (e === 13) {
        console.log('some event there!!!')
    }

},
```

but when i press <kbd>Enter</kbd> nothing happens.

Comment: Are you trying to add the keylistener to the form or to the form field? What version of ExtJS are you using? A bit more code would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a textfield or combobox or trigger or something you can try adding a listener for specialkey:

```
        listeners:{  
            specialkey: function(f,e){  
                if(e.getKey()==e.ENTER){  
                    console.log("I hit enter!"); 
                }  
            }  
        },
```

If it's just hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> anywhere on the window then I'm not as sure.  Something similar might work.

Comment: Check out this guys solution:
http://existdissolve.com/2011/08/extjs-4-adding-an-app-wide-keystroke-mapping/

He uses the S key, but you could change that to the number for ENTER.  He also has "ctrl: true" meaning you have to hit ctrl S.  Remove that if you don't want it.

I put the code from his "launch" section in my main app's "init" function.